# MotionLayout MotionHelper Fade Out Glitch

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

When trying to fade out a TextView in a motion layout, the TextView glitches as shown in the gif

[image: GIF of glitch]

The activity generally follows the example provided by Android Developers on [MotionLayouts and fragment transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motion-layout-examples#fragment_transition_12).

The TextView does not change in position, it is defined to be centred in the fragments.

Has anyone encountered this glitch before? Any comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: Bug reports should be posted on google's issue tracker, not here

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'd just like to check if I'm doing anything wrong / any workarounds before reporting it as a bug

Comment: please post your source code so that we can understand what you are missing

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `android:visibility="gone"` to hide `TextView`s with `MotionLayout` they shrink to the top left anchor